# ZF2 Autoloader: autodiscover classes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, autoloader

I'm trying to figure out if I can use ZF2's Loader/Autoloader to "auto discover" modules and classes. I am not using ZF2 in its native MVC framework structure, but rather as a library.

Current, I have the following structure:

```
/Application
   /Application
   /Module
     /MyCustomModule
       /Controller
          MyCustomModuleController.php
       /Model
       /View
   /Vendor
     /zendframework
     /randomLibrary
```

In my Autoloader setup, I have the following:

```
array(
    'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
        'namespaces' => array(
             'Zend' => $filedir . '/Application/Vendor/Zend/',
     ),
     'fallback_autoloader' => $fallback,
      ),
);
```

Is there a way that I can get the loader to auto discover the module and class: `MyCustomModuleController` which has a FQN of `MyCustomModule\Controller\MyCustomModuleController`
with a resource location path of: `./Application/Module/MyCustomModule/Controller/MyCustomerModuleConstroller.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a line to the autoloader setup file ?
I mean, something like this:

```
array(
    'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
        'namespaces' => array(
            'Zend' => $filedir . '/Application/Vendor/Zend/',
            'MyCustomModule' => $filedir .'/Module/MyCustomModule/',
        ),
        'fallback_autoloader' => $fallback,
    ),
);
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid registering each module